# How to use webpack plugin with Angular Cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I create new project with angular cli. Angular version is 5.

How can I use some webpack plugins in the cli build process without moving out of the cli?

Comment: AFAIK, the only solutions are to eject, or to fork the CLI and modify it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the webpack configuration of a CLI project, you will have to [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) the project.

*Ejecting a CLI project doesn't mean you are moving out of the CLI.* In fact, you can continue to use many CLI commands in your project. Commands to create new components, or any other code scaffolding commands are still available. Commands to build and serve the application are replaced by npm scripts. You will see the new commands to use when you run `ng eject`.

Comment: Eject is currently disabled